# Number of observations in plm package, n, T, N

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am using the `plm` package to estimate pooled OLS and fixed effect models. My data set has 130 countries over 33 years with lots of missing values. My model has 9 independent variables. When I estimate my models I get the following output:

```
Unbalanced Panel: n=34, T=1-6, N=61
```

Can any body explain this? Does it mean that 61 countries have observations for all 33 years across the 9 independent variables?

I saw the same question asked here: [Interpreting plm output in R - number of observations used with very unbalanced panel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85681/interpreting-plm-output-in-r-number-of-observations-used-with-very-unbalanced)

Comment: See my answer to the same question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/219037/9866)

Answer (score 2):

Unbalanced panel simply means you have unequal observations (N) over time period (T) for different units (n, countries in your case).