# Finding intercept term in fixed effects model

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am using the `plm()` function in R with a fixed effects model:

```
fixed <- plm(Y ~ X, data = pdata, index = c("sireID", "cropNum"), model = "within")
```

The output is then:

```
> summary(fixed)
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = Y ~ X, data = pdata, model = "within")

Unbalanced Panel: n = 256, T = 1-16, N = 1039

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-12.2822  -2.1441   0.0000   1.8906  32.6836 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
X1 0.643017   0.042771 15.0340   <2e-16 ***
X2 1.945723   1.745879  1.1145   0.2654    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    17203
Residual Sum of Squares: 13330
R-Squared:      0.2251
Adj. R-Squared: -0.029887
F-statistic: 113.439 on 2 and 781 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

I want to obtain the intercept for this fixed effects model. Is this possible to do using `plm` in R? I tried using the solution given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435821/need-intercept-for-plm-fixed-effects-in-r) by adding `effect = "twoways"` to the `plm()` function but this didn't produce an intercept term.

Comment: Well, read the post you linked till the end and look at the linked `within_intercept` function of package plm (and the literature cited for the theoretical background).

Comment: @Helix123 You're correct. I updated my answer in case the OP is looking for this. The overall intercept is just a weighted mean of all the state effects. I'm not actually sure why this is useful though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fixed effects model your estimating is akin to estimating a separate intercept for each `sireID`. The unit-specific intercepts don't appear in your summary output, but you can ask for them with the following function: `fixef(fixed)`.

Estimating fixed effects along the other dimension (e.g., `effect = "twoways`) isn't going to return a global intercept. The main takeaway from the post you referenced is that the overall intercept $\alpha$ is perfectly collinear with $\alpha_i$, as the sum of all the unit-specific effects (i.e., $\alpha_i$'s) is one.

Estimating your equation using `lm()` and including dummies for all units will return an intercept, but the intercept is simply the effect for the omitted dummy. To see this in practice, I will use the `Produc` dataset (U.S. state production from 1970 to 1986) from the `plm` package.

```
# Load the plm package and the Produc dataset

library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Estimate a one-way fixed effects model
# Extract the state-specific intercepts

mod_within <- plm(hwy ~ gsp, index = c("state", "year"), model = "within", effect = "individual", data = Produc)
summary(fixef(mod_within))
```

The `fixef()` function extracts the fixed effects from a `plm` object. The output below reports the unique state-specific intercepts. Remember the effect for Alabama in the first row.

```
# Summary output from the fixef() function
# These are the state-specific intercepts...

             Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
ALABAMA         7390.71     185.97  39.742 < 2.2e-16 ***
ARIZONA         4749.54     180.96  26.246 < 2.2e-16 ***
ARKANSAS        3761.83     175.90  21.387 < 2.2e-16 ***
CALIFORNIA     37091.91     697.28  53.195 < 2.2e-16 ***
COLORADO        4501.00     186.95  24.076 < 2.2e-16 ***
CONNECTICUT     6142.66     192.52  31.907 < 2.2e-16 ***
DELAWARE        1897.09     171.51  11.061 < 2.2e-16 ***
FLORIDA        13175.73     266.92  49.362 < 2.2e-16 ***
GEORGIA         8331.90     208.42  39.977 < 2.2e-16 ***
IDAHO           2369.09     171.82  13.789 < 2.2e-16 ***
ILLINOIS       22536.50     360.88  62.449 < 2.2e-16 ***
INDIANA         8559.26     213.81  40.033 < 2.2e-16 ***
IOWA            8951.42     184.49  48.520 < 2.2e-16 ***
KANSAS          5983.13     181.48  32.969 < 2.2e-16 ***
KENTUCKY        9925.08     187.95  52.808 < 2.2e-16 ***
LOUISIANA       9972.78     217.73  45.804 < 2.2e-16 ***
MAINE           2205.62     172.15  12.812 < 2.2e-16 ***
MARYLAND        8259.07     198.04  41.704 < 2.2e-16 ***
MASSACHUSETTS   7203.77     225.36  31.965 < 2.2e-16 ***
MICHIGAN       16473.75     288.12  57.178 < 2.2e-16 ***
MINNESOTA      10479.91     199.22  52.604 < 2.2e-16 ***
MISSISSIPPI     5435.86     176.62  30.777 < 2.2e-16 ***
MISSOURI        9406.42     206.89  45.465 < 2.2e-16 ***
MONTANA         3644.11     171.82  21.208 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEBRASKA        4359.62     175.03  24.907 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEVADA          1969.22     172.23  11.434 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEW_HAMPSHIRE   1965.13     171.93  11.430 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEW_JERSEY     10672.72     262.80  40.612 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEW_MEXICO      3158.47     174.12  18.140 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEW_YORK       29833.23     529.86  56.304 < 2.2e-16 ***
NORTH_CAROLINA  7987.01     212.46  37.593 < 2.2e-16 ***
NORTH_DAKOTA    2746.73     171.58  16.008 < 2.2e-16 ***
OHIO           21086.53     317.17  66.484 < 2.2e-16 ***
OKLAHOMA        5029.61     188.38  26.700 < 2.2e-16 ***
OREGON          5566.66     180.65  30.815 < 2.2e-16 ***
PENNSYLVANIA   21292.22     325.81  65.351 < 2.2e-16 ***
RHODE_ISLAND    1783.01     172.00  10.366 < 2.2e-16 ***
SOUTH_CAROLINA  3806.90     179.89  21.162 < 2.2e-16 ***
SOUTH_DAKOTA    3024.36     171.36  17.650 < 2.2e-16 ***
TENNESSE        9005.20     195.23  46.125 < 2.2e-16 ***
TEXAS          24581.81     464.77  52.890 < 2.2e-16 ***
UTAH            3296.01     173.52  18.995 < 2.2e-16 ***
VERMONT         1792.38     171.08  10.477 < 2.2e-16 ***
VIRGINIA       11836.57     212.64  55.666 < 2.2e-16 ***
WASHINGTON      9110.27     198.90  45.804 < 2.2e-16 ***
WEST_VIRGINIA   6054.88     175.35  34.530 < 2.2e-16 ***
WISCONSIN       9116.06     203.39  44.820 < 2.2e-16 ***
WYOMING         2703.02     171.94  15.721 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Estimating dummies for each state using `lm()` results in equivalent estimates. However, we must drop a state since all the state dummies sum to one. The `state` variable in the `Produc` dataset is a factor variable; it's ordered alphabetically. R drops the first factor by default, which is Alabama.

```
# The least squares dummy variable (LSDV) estimator
# Include a dummy variable for each unit (i.e., state)

mod_lsdv <- lm(hwy ~ gsp + as.factor(state), data = Produc)

# Extract the intercept

mod_lsdv$coefficients['(Intercept)']
(Intercept) 
    7390.71
```

Note how the indicator for Alabama doesn't necessarily get dropped; it actually gets *absorbed* into the intercept. The omitted state effect could be any state in the panel.

In short, the intercepts usually aren't the focus in a fixed effects analysis; they're nuisance. In your case, the principal focus should be on `X1` and `X2`.

---

In accordance with the suggestion provided by @Helix123, I wanted to note that there is, in fact, a `within_intercept()` function in the `plm` package. I always found it a bit artificial but it does return an "overall intercept" for within models and its accompanying standard error.

Under the hood, it's actually a *weighted mean* of the fixed effects. You could calculate this fairly easily in the one-way case using the following code:

```
# The overall intercept is just a weighted mean of the state effects

weighted.mean(fixef(mod_within), pdim(mod_within)$Tint$Ti)
```

Simply feed the `weighted.mean()` function the individual state effects, followed by a numeric vector of the weights, and you got your overall intercept.

Comment: Have a look at plm's `within_intercept` and `?within_intercept` (esp. the examples section) for the relation of `fixef` to the overall intercept of a fixed effect model.