# Questions about the constant value of a fixed effects model in Python’s PanelOLS

Tags: python, panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model, intercept

I have a question about the constant value of a fixed effects model.

I am currently conducting research using a fixed effects model that controls for the effects of companies using Python's `linearmodels` package.

These are the results from Python and Stata when analyzing the same model.

[image: python panelols]

[image: Stata fe model result]

It's not exactly the same, but you can see that most of the results are similar. However, in Stata’s result, one constant coefficient value and standard error value are shown, but Python does not show a constant.

In many research papers they show a constant value for fixed effects models, and I want to show that one intercept value and $p$-value can be obtained in my research.

I also looked up a lot of Internet data and looked for results like Stata's constant, but I couldn't find a way in Python (PanelOLS) or R (plm), so I'd like to ask experts in this forum.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS

model = PanelOLS.from_formula(‘Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5  + EntityEffects', data = df.set_index(['firm', 'date']))
results = model.fit(cov_type = 'clustered', cluster_entity = True)
```

Comment: Welcome. Did you ask for the intercept? You didn't show your code so I can't offer anything specific, but suppose you fit your model in Python and stored the results in, say, `results`. Try `results.params['const']`. In Stata, and most other software packages, the intercept is the average value of the fixed effects. In R, try the `within_intercept()` function in the `plm` package (see my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538847/finding-intercept-term-in-fixed-effects-model) for more on this).

Comment: Thank you so much for the Great answer. Come to think of it, I didn't attach my Python code. I currently uploaded Python code I had tied. And I used PanelOLS in Linearmodel package.

Comment: When I used the Python code you taught me, I wasn't sure how to derive the one constant value from whole model. `results.params[‘const’] ` Could you explain more detail?

Comment: First, were you able to extract the coefficient(s)?

Comment: You mean every, each firms and day coefficients? It comes from `results.estimated_effects` isn’t it?

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure the recommended code worked. Second, why the interest in the intercept?

Comment: Yes, I can extract all firms and days coefficients from `results.estimated_effects` code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131764/discussion-between-chocolate-coffee-and-thomas-bilach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the intercept, then try extracting it manually. In Python's `linearmodels` package, try the `params` attribute, indexing by the constant term:

```
results = model.fit(...)
results.params['const']
```

Or, if you want all the estimated panel level effects, then try using the `estimated_effects` attribute:

```
results = model.fit(...)
results.estimated_effects
```

In my opinion, the [git](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults.html#linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults) documentation is *in*exhaustive to say the least, but it should help to get you what you want.

---

In Stata, the intercept is succinctly referred to as the "average value" of the fixed effects. To be clear, you're actually considering the following fixed effects model:

$$
y_{it} = \alpha + x_{it}'\beta + \mu_{i} + \epsilon_{it},
$$

where $\alpha$ is a global intercept (i.e., constant term) and $\mu_{i}$ denotes entity (e.g., individual, firm, state, etc.) fixed effects. Note how you cannot estimate a constant term *and* the entity-specific effects without imposing some kind of constraint. The constraint StataCorp places on the system is that the panel fixed effects sum to 0 across all observations in the sample.

In short, the "intercept" in `-xtreg, fe-` is the average of $\alpha + \mu_{i}$. Stata's support [page](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/intercept-in-fixed-effects-model/) discusses this in further detail.

---

R's `plm` package estimates a *within model* using the following equation:

$$
y_{it} = \alpha_{i} + x_{it}'\beta + \epsilon_{it},
$$

where $\alpha_{i}$ denotes entity fixed effects. This amounts to fitting a separate intercept for each unit in your panel. Note how the overall intercept parameter, $\alpha$ (*un*subscripted), is not specified. In this context, $\alpha$ would be perfectly collinear with $\alpha_{i}$, as the sum of all the entity-specific effects (i.e., $\alpha_{i}$'s) is one. In R, we can extract these entity-specific intercepts (i.e., fixed effects) from a `plm` object using the `fixef()` function.

I should also note that a `within_intercept()` function is also available in the `plm` package. I always found it a bit artificial but it does return an "overall intercept" for within models and its accompanying standard error. Under the hood, it's simply a *weighted mean* of the fixed effects. Review my response [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538847/finding-intercept-term-in-fixed-effects-model) or this answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435821/need-intercept-for-plm-fixed-effects-in-r) for other R applications.

---

In sum, I wouldn't go looking for consistency across statistical software packages. In my opinion, the intercept is a trivial parameter in fixed effects applications. It's generally safe to omit.