# Is this the correct way to estimate a Difference-in-Differences model in R (multiple periods and states)?

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, multicollinearity, difference-in-difference

First, I would like to say that I'm not sure if this is a question for CrossValidated or StackOverflow, as the question relates both to coding and statistics.

**My Q**: I would like to know if this is the right way to code the following Difference-in-Differences model with time and state effects.

$$Y = \alpha + \beta_1 TREAT + \gamma (MONTH\times TREAT) + \lambda MONTH + \sigma STATE$$

where TREAT is equal to 1 for the treatment group, 0 otherwise. $MONTH$ is a set of month dummies (1-15), and $STATE$ is a set of dummies for all US states. All variables are coded as factor variables (except $Y$, which is employment).

in R using the `fixest` package:

```
feols(y ~ treat + i(month, treat, ref = 12) | month + state, data = emp)
```

(the reference month is 12, that is May 2021).

However, this model gives an error: "The variable 'treat' has been removed because of **collinearity**". I've tried to follow this (see first answer): [Specifying a difference in differences model with multiple time periods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/specifying-a-difference-in-differences-model-with-multiple-time-periods).

The goal is to do a DiD with time and state effects. I was fairly certain that I've specified the model correctly, but the error makes me think that I got the R code wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I will add some explanation to make things a bit more clear. First, in my actual model in R, the $MONTH$ variable is actually called `period` and $STATE$ is called `Delstat`.

Now, as you can tell by looking at the table, I have two models. The first one is a basic DiD with state and time effects. Here, the interaction is `treat:after` and month/period is used as time effects - we also have state/Delstat as unit effects. Note that `after` = 1 starting from the treatment month (June = Period 13), 0 otherwise.

Here's the code for model 1:

```
lm(emp ~ treat + treat:after + period + Delstat, data = emp_clean)
```

**Note** that `period` and `Delstat` in the model are coded as factors, i.e., `factor(period)`.

[image]

So now my idea is to make a **second model**. I believe it's usually referred to as a DiD model with **dynamic effects**. As I understand it, you should interact the treatment variable with the time variable - we are looking at month effects, so that's why we use $\gamma (MONTH\times TREAT)$ in our model.

As I understand it, you want all of the interaction variable coefficients before the treatment month to be "statistically" equal to 0 - which, I think, is a kind of formal test of the parallel trends assumption. I *think* they are called **placebo coefficients**?

If you look at our results, these coefficients are basically 0 (before and after the treatment in June). However, recall that my original problem is that R's `feols()` drops the treatment variable because of **collinearity**. That's basically what I'm trying to fix. Although it might be that there is some other problem with my set-up!?

**EDIT 2**

Here's an `reprex()` of my data and code:

```
# DATA

emp_clean <- structure(
  list(
    period = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
      .Label = c("12",
                 "11", "13", "14"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    Delstat = structure(
      c(1L,
        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
      .Label = c("Alabama", "California"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    emp = c(0.0531, -0.0913, 0.038, -0.105, 0.0548, -0.0925),
    treat = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    after = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# mod1 and mod2

library(fixest)

dd1 <- lm(emp ~ treat + treat:after + period + Delstat, data = emp_clean)

dd2 <- feols(emp ~ treat + i(period, treat, ref = 12) | period + Delstat, data = emp_clean )
```

Comment: It seems like the state effects absorb your treatment indicator. Does your treatment start at the same time for all treated states?

Comment: Yes, they do. In reality treatment starts a few day apart in June - but I've set it as June 1 for all states. I assume this might be the source of collinearity? Otherwise, does it look ok?

Comment: Just to be clear. Treat is = 1 for everyone in the treatment group at all time. Before and after the treatment period. 0 for the control group.

Comment: I should add that the panel is monthly-data.  I guess I'm unsure how I would change the treatment start time, if you think that is necessary...

Comment: Before we address the collinearity concern, do you even have *daily* data?

Comment: I do have daily data. I've converted it to monthly data, as daily seemed to fine-grained for employment effects (of unemployment insurance). I will say though, that I'm a bit concerned on doing DiD on daily data because of how the regression output will look, i.e to many coefficients. But maybe there is a way to deal with that aswell?

Comment: What do you think @ThomasBilach ?

Comment: I think I will answer your question soon :) Unless someone else addresses it first.

Comment: Before I submit my answer, I have one additional follow-up question. Why did you interact the treatment dummy with a full series of month indicators? Do you want to do some sort of event study analysis as well?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I added more info to the question. I will try and upload the code / data asap. I think that might help...

Comment: Added data and models, as well :)

Comment: Also, is the time chronology properly preserved? I noticed November precedes October in your tabular results.

Comment: Apparently I misslabled November/October, thanks for pointing that out. As for your, very genourous reply, I will get back to you in a few days when I've had the time to look it through properly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model includes both state *and* month fixed effects. The state fixed effects, in particular, adjust for all *time-constant* factors, including a state's membership to the treatment group. Note that you defined $TREAT$ as equal to 1 if a state is in the treatment group, 0 otherwise. By its very definition, a state's treatment status doesn't change over time. A state is either in one of two groups: the treatment group or the control group. Time-invariant "group membership" is already accounted for by the inclusion of state fixed effects.

You could actually specify your equation more simply given that the "timing" of the policy (i.e., treatment) is standardized among treated states, at least this is the case using a monthly time frequency. The classical difference-in-differences equation looks like the following:

$$
y_{st} = \alpha + \sigma T_s + \lambda A_t + \delta (T_s \times A_t) + u_{st}
$$

where you observe outcome $y$ in state $s$ in month $t$. $T_s$ is equal to 1 if a state is in the treatment group, 0 otherwise. This is the same as $TREAT$ in your earlier equation. $A_t$ is a time dummy equal to 1 in the months after treatment in both groups, 0 otherwise. The product of these two terms returns the difference-in-differences estimate.

The generalization of this equation regresses $y_{st}$ on a full set of state effects, a full set of month effects, and a treatment indicator. Here is the basic two-way fixed effects equation:

$$
y_{st} = \sigma_s + \lambda_t + \delta D_{st} + u_{st}
$$

where the parameters $\sigma_s$ and $\lambda_t$ denote fixed effects for states and months, respectively. A quick word with respect to the month fixed effects. To be precise, the model requires a variable denoting all months—not a repeating sequence of say, months 1–12. In other words, if you have 15 months, then you need a variable that uniquely delineates all 15 periods. $D_{st}$ is the interaction term just defined in a different way (i.e., $D_{st} = T_s \times P_t$). In most applications, $D_{st}$ is a dichotomous policy variable indexing when a policy 'turns on' (i.e., switches from 0 to 1) in state $s$ by month $t$, 0 otherwise.

In your second model, it appears you want to interact $T_s$ with a series of month indicators. Here is one of the many ways to specify your equation:

$$
y_{st} = \sigma_s + \lambda_t + \delta^{k} (T_s \times M^{k}_{t}) + u_{st},
$$

where $M^{k}_{t}$ represents a series of month dummies for the $k$ periods before *and* after treatment. Note how the constituent elements of the product term don't appear in this equation. The individual main effects are redundant with the state and month fixed effects. What's important in this setting is the interactions of $T_s$ with the month dummies; these coefficients remain. Let's see this in action.

To begin, I augmented your panel a bit. If we used the abridged data frame included in your post, we don't have enough residual degrees of freedom to estimate dynamic treatment effects. To make this work in practice, I "lengthened" your panel. Now we have 3 states observed over a 9-month period. I also simulated new $y$-values. Here is the result of `emp_clean`:

```
## Augmented data frame

 # N x T = 27
 # 3 states
 # 9 months

 # Alabama is treated
 # California and Louisiana serve as controls
 # The treatment is adopted uniformly in month 13 onward

## Variables

 # delstat = unit (state) identifier
 # period  = time (month) indicator
 # emp     = outcome
 # treat   = treatment indicator
 # after   = post-treatment indicator
 # policy  = policy dummy (treat x after)

# A tibble: 27 × 6
   delstat    period   emp treat after policy
   <fct>      <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Alabama    8       4.59     1     0      0
 2 Alabama    9       4.96     1     0      0
 3 Alabama    10      5.83     1     0      0
 4 Alabama    11      5.23     1     0      0
 5 Alabama    12      5.22     1     0      0
 6 Alabama    13      9.97     1     1      1
 7 Alabama    14     10.0      1     1      1
 8 Alabama    15      9.85     1     1      1
 9 Alabama    16      9.95     1     1      1
10 Louisiana  8       4.32     0     0      0
11 Louisiana  9       5.13     0     0      0
12 Louisiana  10      5.19     0     0      0
13 Louisiana  11      4.33     0     0      0
14 Louisiana  12      4.36     0     0      0
15 Louisiana  13      5.46     0     1      0
16 Louisiana  14      5.39     0     1      0
17 Louisiana  15      4.56     0     1      0
18 Louisiana  16      4.72     0     1      0
19 California 8       4.95     0     0      0
20 California 9       7.28     0     0      0
21 California 10      7.01     0     0      0
22 California 11      2.53     0     0      0
23 California 12      5.29     0     0      0
24 California 13      4.77     0     1      0
25 California 14      3.92     0     1      0
26 California 15      3.15     0     1      0
27 California 16      4.07     0     1      0
```

Now that we have some data to work with, let's quickly review a base R solution. Note that your policy uniformly affects all states in the same month. In other words, treatment *timing* is the same across all states. If this is truly the case, then the two equations specified below should produce equivalent estimates of the treatment effect.

```
## Model 1 - Classical DiD (2x2)

lm(emp ~ treat*after, data = emp_clean)

## Model 2 - Generalized DiD (Multiple Groups/Time Periods)

lm(emp ~ policy + as.factor(delstat) + as.factor(period), data = emp_clean)
```

Now let's estimate some models using the `fixest` package. If you don't want any redundancies, simply include the `policy` variable on the left-hand side of the `|`. Here is the basic structure:

```
feols(emp ~ policy | delstat + period, data = emp_clean)
```

Collinearity should be non-existent, assuming you created the policy variable appropriately. On the other hand, including the interaction term directly (i.e., `treat*after`) *before* the `|` works as well, but R warns you that the constituent elements of the product term are collinear with the fixed effects. R is actually doing the right thing; it's dropping the redundant terms for you without any additional work on your part. Here's the summary output:

```
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: emp
Observations: 27 
Fixed-effects: delstat: 3,  period: 9
Standard-errors: Clustered (delstat) 
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
policy    5.325   0.962008  5.5353 0.031122 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 0.678526     Adj. R2: 0.806451
                 Within R2: 0.771657
```

The coefficient on `policy` should be similar to the estimates using `lm()`.

The next equation is estimating dynamic treatment effects. The `feols()` function allows you to easily specify a reference period. I assume the twelfth period is the month immediately *before* the treatment goes into effect. In most applications, it's quite common to omit the period before policy adoption. Here is the basic structure:

```
feols(emp ~ i(treat, period, ref = 12) | delstat + period, data = emp_clean)
```

This is typically referred to as an "event study" model. The name is quite fitting, as we're trying to exploit some "event" of interest. In the pre-policy periods, the confidence intervals associated with each interaction *should* bound zero. Here's the summary output:

```
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: emp
Observations: 27 
Fixed-effects: delstat: 3,  period: 9
Standard-errors: Clustered (delstat) 
                  Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
treat:period::8  -0.442994   0.206997 -2.140100 0.165703    
treat:period::9  -1.645000   0.848225 -1.939300 0.192019    
treat:period::10 -0.663947   0.620491 -1.070000 0.396622    
treat:period::11  1.403200   1.903700  0.737071 0.537818    
treat:period::13  4.460200   1.135900  3.926700 0.059160 .  
treat:period::14  4.998100   1.668700  2.995200 0.095729 .  
treat:period::15  5.603500   1.628100  3.441700 0.075042 .  
treat:period::16  5.159200   1.098100  4.698100 0.042442 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 0.567197     Adj. R2: 0.746413
                 Within R2: 0.84044
```

Indeed, it's correct to call the estimates in the pre-policy epoch "placebo" effects/coefficients. We are deliberately defining the periods *before* the event as the actual treatment periods. In essence, these are "fake" treatments. We shouldn't be observing the effects of a state-wide policy/law emerge before it's actually enacted! All the action should be concentrated in the post-policy epoch. I artificially simulated values to show you this, but your results could look quite different in practice. In your post, your tabular results suggest a delayed policy effect, but it's hard to say without acquiring more data beyond August.

In short, you should only concern yourself with the coefficients on the interaction terms. Including $TREAT$, by itself, has no effect on your point estimates. Time-invariant state-level attributes are collinear with the state fixed effects. Even if you did include $TREAT$, R will safely exclude it.

Comment: Like I wrote above, thanks for this very generous reply. I will probably get back with some comments when I've read through your reply more carefully. I think there is one mistake. In the dynamic model, you write `i(period, treat , ref = 12)`, which prompts an error because period needs to be the second variable. I believe they changed the order in the latest update of the fixest package. Again, many thanks!

Comment: No problem. As far as the issue with the code, `period` is in the second position in my answer, no?

Comment: That was weird! I was sure I ctrl+c your code, and it was definitely not in the second position in my R script. Sorry,  my mistake. It's late here in Sweden :)

Comment: It’s in the first position in your post. Honest mistake. Follow-up if I’ve written anything that is unclear!

Comment: Here's a few follow up questions:

1. In your reply, the second, third and fourth model does not have an intercept, why is that? 
2. The third and fourth are the same right? The only exception is that in the 3rd model you use P (for period?) and in the 4th you use M for month.
3. We did not say anything about Standard Errors. I might just mention it, just to add more info for future readers. I cluster my SEs on the state level (~Delstat), which is `vcov =~Delstat` in the modelsummary-package. 

Finally, yes, it is correct that period 12 is the reference period!

Comment: Another thing that I didn't understand. You write " If this is truly the case, then the two equations specified below should produce equivalent estimates of the treatment effect." I don't understand how to compare these two models as they are quite different. Which specific coefficients do you mean are supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: In a fixed effects specification, we usually omit the intercept. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538847/finding-intercept-term-in-fixed-effects-model) for more on this. As for your other concern, `fixest` clustered on states by default. And yes, the twelfth period is explicitly omitted as a reference.

Comment: Models 1 and 2 show a base R solution. What I meant is that the coefficients on `treat*after` and `policy` should be similar. If the treatment starts at the same time in all states, then you can use either equation. The latter equation is a just a generalization of the former equation.

Comment: I think I got most of it now. Thanks so much for explaining it all!