# Least-Squares Dummy Variables Estimator

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Is the Least-Squares Dummy Variables Estimator always strictly less efficient than the fixed effects estimator?

Comment: Since they are the same thing, no: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174243/difference-between-fixed-effects-dummies-and-fixed-effects-estimator/174267#174267