statsmodels: Update OLS' degrees of freedom when absorbing 3+ fixed effects
I want to run an OLS regression with 3+ fixed effects.
(Whether this is a good idea is out of the scope of this question).
I can do it using Stata:
ssc install reghdfe
webuse nlswork
reghdfe ln_wage hours tenure, absorb(age union race) vce(cluster ind_code)

Now, I want to replicate this in Python. I've downloaded the example dataset locally, and can implement it naively by creating dummies for each fixed effect, and results are similar to Stata's:
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_stata("path/to/nlswork.dta")
dataset = df.dropna(
    subset=[
        "ln_wage",
        "hours",
        "tenure",
        "age",
        "union",
        "race",
        "ind_code",
    ],
    how="any",
)

model = sm.ols(
    formula="ln_wage ~ hours + tenure + C(age) + C(union) + C(race)",
    data=dataset,
)
results = model.fit(
    cov_type="cluster",
    cov_kwds={"groups": np.array(dataset["ind_code"])},
    use_t=True,
)

print(results.summary())

However, this isn't feasible with high-dimension fixed effects (e.g. try replacing race with idcode and the model takes more than a minute to fit).
I understand that I can absorb the fixed effects beforehand, and run the OLS on the residuals. I understand that I need to adjust the model's degrees of freedom to account for those absorbed.
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pyhdfe

df = pd.read_stata("path/to/nlswork.dta")
dataset = df.dropna(
    subset=[
        "ln_wage",
        "hours",
        "tenure",
        "age",
        "union",
        "idcode",
        "ind_code",
    ],
    how="any",
)

# Encode race
pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
dataset["race_id"] = dataset["race"].astype("category").cat.codes

columns_of_interest = ["ln_wage", "hours", "tenure", "race_id", "ind_code"]

algorithm = pyhdfe.create(
    dataset[["age", "union", "race_id"]],
    drop_singletons=True,
)

demeaned_dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    data=algorithm.residualize(dataset[columns_of_interest]),
    columns=columns_of_interest
)
model = sm.ols(
    formula="ln_wage ~ hours + tenure",
    data=demeaned_dataset,
)

# Adjust degrees of freedom
model.df_model += algorithm.degrees
model.df_resid -= algorithm.degrees

results = model.fit(
    cov_type="cluster",
    cov_kwds={"groups": np.array(demeaned_dataset["ind_code"])},
    use_t=True,
)

print(results.summary())

While coefficients are correct, the t-stats are off. What am I missing?

I can't read Python code but guess that t-stats involve an error variance estimate which takes into account a df correction for the number of regressors fitted. And each fixed effect effectively is, being a unit specific intercept, another parameter, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174243/difference-between-fixed-effects-dummies-and-fixed-effects-estimator/174267#174267. Now, your second stage cannot "know" anymore that the regressors you're handing to it result from implicitly having fitted such coefficients in a first stage. Though, that may be what algorithm.degrees does.

Since you appear to be using clustered standard errors (not sure how these are constructed exactly) that may not be enough, though

Try nonrobust cov_type to see whether the corrected df_model, df_resid are used.

@ChristophHanck algorithm.degrees is the "number of degrees of freedom used by the fixed effects" (cf. docs). Originally, model.df_model equals 2 (hours and tenure, which aren't correlated).

In that case, that, if I understand correctly, would then not be "enough", see my answer below: even with a single fixed effect, you would need a correction equal to the number of different groups in that fixed effect

as reference for equivalence or non-equivalence of robust standard errors with and without absorbing https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2020.108945 and https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2307.00369  (statsmodels tracking issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9253 )

In R, the following correction restores equality of the (nonrobust) s.e.s of the residual-based regression to the fixed-effects based ones:
library(Jmisc)
library(plm)

# panel dimensions
m = 20
n = 8

# generate some data
step = 5
alpha = runif(n,seq(0,step*n,by=step),seq(step,step*n+step,by=step))
beta = -2
y = X = matrix(NA,nrow=m,ncol=n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  X[,i] = rnorm(m,i)
  y[,i] = alpha[i] + X[,i]*beta + rnorm(m,sd=1.5)  
}
stackX = as.vector(X)
stackY = as.vector(y)

# columnwise demeaning for OLS on residuals
MX = as.vector(demean(X))
My = as.vector(demean(y))

paneldata = data.frame(rep(1:n,each=m),rep(1:m,n),stackY,stackX) # first two columns are for plm to understand the panel structure

options(digits=10)
# the following return the same values for the standard errors:
summary(plm(stackY~stackX, data = paneldata, model = "within"))$coefficients[2]
summary(lm(My~MX-1))$coefficients[2]*sqrt((m*n-1)/(m*n-n-1)) 

